# Вертикальная прокрутка пунктов меню в открывающемся блоке

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

http://testbcard.bootstrap.dtraduga.vh55.hosterby.com/discounts_for_points.php#

Разрешение: 767 и меньше.
Вверху справа нажимаем выбрать город > Открывается меню с списком городов.
Как сделать чтобы города скролились по вертикали в видимой области меню (высота открывающегося меню 100vh).
Сами скролы не нужны.

Comment: ни шиша не открывается при клике по ссылке "выбрать город".

Comment: Прошу прощения. Новый линк: http://testbcard.dtraduga.vh55.hosterby.com/discounts_for_points.php#   Сейчас уже все скролится, сделали - но появилась новая проблема.

Comment: Если находишься на странице скидок то при выборе раздела СКИДКИ и попытке выбрать СКИДКИ по МОЦНАЙ КАРТКЕ, данный пункт не выбрать, точнее там примерно 1px для этого. Это его перекрывает 2 меню с которыми были проблемы изначально: http://prntscr.com/jovxk6 Пробовад z-index чтобы было поверх всего, но не получилось (((